# Grouping by filter of another collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I'm using **Meteor** and **MongoDB**. I need to publish with aggregation (I'm using **jcbernack:reactive-aggregate** and **ReactiveAggregate**).

```
db.getCollection('Jobs').aggregate([ 
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "JobMatches",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "jobId",
      as: "matches"
    }
},
{ $project: 
  { 
    matches: { 
        '$filter': { 
            input: '$matches', 
            as: 'match', 
            cond: { '$and': [{$eq: ['$$match.userId', userId]}]}
        }
    }
   }
},
{$match:  { 'matches.score': { '$gte': 60 }},
{$sort: { "matches.score": -1 }},
{$limit: 6}
```

])

On the client I get only the **data part** (limit 6). So I will have to count the number of all the data on the server side. I can't use `find().count()` because in the `find()` call without aggregation I can't use a filter associated with  other collection (like this `{ 'matches.score': { '$gte': 60 }`). How can I calculate the data filtered in this way? There may be a need to use a **$group** in the **pipeline**?

Comment: What are you asking? How to get the count of what? If you just want the count then run another aggregation with `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count': { "$sum" :1 } } }` after the `$match` stage instead of the other pipeline stages. But **please** don not try and do this in one request. Or even ask for that.

Comment: Neil Lunn, I need to count the number of **Jobs** given filter `{$match:  { 'matches.score': { '$gte': 60 }}`. If I use `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count': { "$sum" :1 } } }` then I get the count of **all** data without filter.

Comment: It's a "pipeline stage". Use your above aggregation pipeline just the same, but instead of the `$sort, $limit` stages, just replace those with the `$group` I just gave you, right **after** the `$match`. Then you are counting the documents once both the `$lookup` and `$match` are applied. So `$lookup -> $match -> $group` should then be the new pipeline for the count.

Comment: Oh, it really works! I should have known myself. Thank you very much!